# How do I use Jquery to find and select a Multi Select option by the Value?

Tags: jquery, html-select, multi-select

I can't seem to figure out how to correctly select a Multi Select option by the Value and leave the other options that are selected alone.

Update 
It does work, thanks! I had the multi-select hidden and I thought firebug would update the option to "selected" but it doesn't. When I "show" the multi-select box after setting the attr to selected, it was selected. So that was also part of my problem, what firebug was showing me behind the scene.

Comment: You can select option by value $("#multiselect > option[value='yourvaluehere']") Sorry, I can't understand what do you mean saying "and leave the other options that are selected alone"

Comment: I think I was way off, so I was screwing up the other selected options as in nothing was selected anymore. Using what you have, I presume that will find it correctly, but then do I use .Attr(seleected, "selected") after that?

Comment: $("#multiselect > option[value='yourvaluehere']").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: Hmm, I can return the $("#multiselect > option[value='yourvaluehere']").val() in an alert, but the option isn't getting selected.

Comment: The O'Reilly's new "jQuery Cookbook" has tons of examples that show how to do in-depth selection like this

Comment: @ChrisTek, I will have to take a look at that book, I unfortunately find the jquery docs hard to understand, partly because it is new to me and I find the examples hokie, just me probably.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To select an individual option, leaving the rest alone:

```
$("#selectID option[value='" + myValue + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Or, alternatively since `.val()` returns an Array in the multiselect case:

```
var vals = $("#selectID").val();
vals.push(myValue);
$("#selectID").val(vals);
```

Comment: It does work, thanks! I had the multi-select hidden and I thought firebug would update the option to "selected" but it doesn't. When I "show" the box after setting the attr, it was selected. So that was also part of my problem, what firebug was showing me behind the scene.

Comment: @gnarf - I agree that .val() solution will be very handy!

Comment: hi, I have tried both the options but its not working for multiple values. Its only working for single value..

Comment: @Alok you'd add to the array each option you want to push in the multiple case.  Also that only works on an actual select multiple. If you're having trouble definitely ask a question with your exact case and code so we can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to find and select multi select dropdown

```
 $('#selectID ').children("option[value=" + myValue + "]").prop("selected", true);
```